# .NET Framework 4.8 redistributable does not apply to this operating system

Tags: frameworks

Tried to install Remote Desktop and it required .NET Framework 4.8
While installing this version, this problem appeared

```
**The .NET Framework 4.8 redistributable does not apply to this operating system. Please download the .NET Framework 4.8 for your operating system**
```

look the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfjl7.png)

Comment: it seems like you're trying to install something; if you're downloading something for this - check what OS you're downloading it for, but: remote desktop is part of the OS itself, so... not sure what you're doing here. Either way, it doesn't sound like a programming question, so it probably isn't suitable for this site.

Comment: This is true
It's not a programming question, but I don't know where this question is